# 15.04 upstart&systemd boot problem

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 15.04, upstart, systemd

I upgraded to Kubuntu 15.04 and cannot start using either systemd or upstart without going into rescue mode.  I switched from systemd to upstart without any change.  It hangs at the Kubuntu logo and must be restarted. I tried deleting the 'quiet, splash' from /etc/default/grub and adding '--debug' but didn't get any help.  My boot.log just has the standard rescue mode scripts.

Comment: I have the same issue on a laptop. But it stays at a black screen. May be related to gfx drivers